# Cannot call procedure from my java class

Tags: java, angularjs, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to call stored procedure from my java class by taking input from angularJs and passing it to stored procedure but its showing error:javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/Oracle -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.Oracle.Please help

java code

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.att.cbe.common.DBConnection;

@Path("/IntakeFormSection")
public class SampleService {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SampleService.class);

@POST
@Path("/print")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postSomeString(String id) {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Start postSomething");

    }

    String response = null;
    System.out.println("my firstname is"+id);
    try {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            logger.debug("in version 1");

        System.out.println("my firstname is" + id);

        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();

        CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("{? = call CAMUNDA.get_notification_for_user(?)}");
        System.out.println("++");
        call.setString(1, id);
        call.executeQuery();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) call.getObject(1);
        System.out.println("my firstname is" + rs.getString(0));
        System.out.println("my firstname is" + id);
        response = id;
        call.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        response = e.getMessage().toString();
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("result: '" + response + "'");
        logger.debug("End postSomething");
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

AngularJs Code
    
     
     
    
    Insert title here

```
<script src="lib/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="post_ctrl">

<script type="text/javascript">
var myapp=angular.module('myapp',[])
myapp.controller('post_ctrl',function($scope,$http){

$scope.fun=function(){
$scope.data=$scope.firstname;
$scope.jsonObj = angular.toJson($scope.data, false);
var response =          $http.post('http://localhost:8080/..../rs/IntakeFormSection/print',    $scope.jsonObj);

};});
</script>


<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="firstname"><br>
 <button ng-click="fun()">input</button>



</body>
</html>
```

DBConnection.java

```
public class DBConnection {

private static Connection conn = null;
private static DataSource ds = null;

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public static Connection getConnection() {

    System.out.println("Data connection......");
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) ctx
                .lookup("java:/jdbc/Oracle");
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection object:"+conn);
        return conn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return conn;
    }
}

}
```

Error:

```
  12:34:25,072 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Data      connection......

 12:34:25,086 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/Oracle -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.Oracle

 12:34:25,087 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:103)

 12:34:25,091 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197)

 12:34:25,091 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:120)

 12:34:25,092 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183)

 12:34:25,092 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)

 12:34:25,092 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)

 12:34:25,092 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at com.att.cbe.common.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:19)

 12:34:25,092 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at com.att.cbe.service.SampleService.postSomeString(SampleService.java:48)

 12:34:25,093 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

12:34:25,093 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

12:34:25,093 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

12:34:25,093 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

12:34:25,093 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167)

12:34:25,094 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)

12:34:25,094 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)

12:34:25,094 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)

12:34:25,094 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542)

12:34:25,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)

12:34:25,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126)

12:34:25,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)

12:34:25,095 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)

12:34:25,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)

12:34:25,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

12:34:25,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)

12:34:25,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

12:34:25,096 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)

12:34:25,097 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)

12:34:25,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)

12:34:25,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)

12:34:25,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)

12:34:25,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)

12:34:25,098 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)

12:34:25,099 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Do you have the right JDBC-driver in your Project?

Comment: Did you configure the jdbc datasource on the jboss server on which you are deploying this application? This looks like your server is not able to find your datasource in it's JNDI settings.

Comment: I'm creating a data source in this way:  ds = (DataSource) ctx
                .lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Oracle");  Note that I also have an entry for the data source in my web.xml (though perhaps this may not be required for JBoss)